# MonoDevelop fails when trying to debug on device

Tags: ios, debugging, deployment, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm trying to install the iOS app I'm developing on my device, but each time I try MonoDevelop  crashes. First the CPU usage spikes and then it stops responding. It seems to be failing when the debugger tries to connect to the device. The application is installed on the device and I can use the app, but I need to see the application output.

I'm using the newest version of MonoDevelop and version 6.0.0 of MonoTouch. Are there any other users with the same experience who have solved this problem?

**edit**

this is the version information from monodevelop. I've had to treat it like code because else the stackoverflow editor would have made it unreadable.

```
MonoDevelop 3.1.1
Installation UUID: cf274ee7-dfe8-4ba8-b44c-2c7a0d9a45ab
Runtime:
    Mono 2.10.9 (tarball)
    GTK 2.24.10
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
    Package version: 210090011
Apple Developer Tools:
     Xcode 4.5.2 (1847)
     Build 4G2008a
Monotouch: 6.0.6
Mono for Android: 4.4.55
Android SDK: /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-mac_x86
    Supported Android versions:
        2.1 (API level 7)
        2.2 (API level 8)
        2.3 (API level 10)
        3.1 (API level 12)
        4.0 (API level 14)
        4.1 (API level 16)
        4.2 (API level 17)
Java SDK: /usr
Xamarin.Mac: Not Installed
Build information:
    Release ID: 30101000
    Git revision: 5d928ec4f9d5864b4db04a1301b8a8649b43fb9d
    Build date: 2012-12-14 19:11:30+0000
    Xamarin addins: 80f2dcc8fe4ed316b3e77dde496fc33d90305047
Operating System:
    Mac OS X 10.8.2
    Darwin ---.local 12.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0
        Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012
        root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: Providing the iOS version (of the device) and the Xcode version would be useful. You can get the later from "MonoDevelop" menu, "About MonoDevelop" item, "Version Information" tab. Click on the "Copy Version Information" button and paste this into this bug report.

Comment: Are you pointing me towards a location where I can post a bug or do you want me to post it above?

Comment: Sorry I copy/pasted the above :) You can edit your question to add the extra information (but it might be required to open a bug report later if the information does not help figuring what's happening).

Comment: I've altered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problem was in the end. OS X seemed to have gone corrupt and wouldn't even start properly any more. Besides the problems I had with MonoDevelop I also started having problems in different software. The solution was to do a full clean install of OS X. I have now been able to update MonoDevelop and MonoTouch and can once again debug apps on devices.

I'm sorry if my solution can't help any other people directly, but perhaps the answer Stephane Delcroix gave may help you!

Answer (score 0):

I got that a lot in the past, while working with a library that wasn't available for the simulator. For me, it was (probably) related to usb link. What you should try:

- Turn off itunes (that one is hard to do, you hear a lot of weird sounds around you when music is down)
- Enable debugging over wifi (instead of USB) in monodevelop (Preferences>Debugger>iPhone Debugger)

It helped me, hope it'll help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although it wasn't the solution for me it might help other monodevelop users!